# White blank page for 10 to 15 seconds then suddenly content appears

Tags: 7, theming

My site recently migrated to drupal 7 And it is already having a major page loading performance issues. Now very strange thing is happening to home page before showing accutual content it is  displaying a white blank page for 10 to 15 seconds and suddenly content appears. I dont know how to solve the issue. Did anybody face such problem before? plz  help

I have already implemented boost caches as well as memcache to speed up the pages

Comment: What is your caching strategy?

Comment: I have implemnted boost caches as well as memcache

Comment: Please add it, with description, directly to your question.

Comment: Does this happen on other browsers as well?  If not, then it could be a plugin on the testing browser.  Also, have you looked at a "Network" tab in your browser's developer tools?  You may find out that your site is completely loaded, but that the browser is waiting until some 3rd party javascript is loaded before showing the page.